# Task scheduler in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduled-tasks

I'm coming from Lua, where it isn't that hard to make a task scheduler to add threads to a queue then resume them once one yields.

I'm wondering if there's something like this in NodeJS. I've seen node-scheduler, but I don't think that does what I want. That schedules specific functions, while I'm looking for a way to resume threads when one yields. For example, if I have two functions with loops in both, and I call both of them, the first will run. Then, in these loops, I use **await**, which yields the thread. When the thread yields, the next function runs until it hits that await, then the other function resumes, and so on.

Is there any way to do this with NodeJS?

Comment: Just google nodejs coroutines. I doubt there's an easy way to do it with actual OS threads (although it's technically possible), but coros should be fast enough.

Comment: checkout `bull` https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull it might be what you neeed

Comment: `await` is probably the way to go. You might want have a look at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/ for what you want to await - nodejs doesn't use multiple threads.